# Pass a struct with a member being vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, parameters, parameter-passing

I have a class which builds a dll, implemented as a single solution. In its header file I have a struct with a member being vector. like following;

```
// dll.h

    struct ScanParam16
    {
        // int param
        int nChanDetX, nChanDetZ;
        int nViewPerRot, nViewPerSlice, 
            nChanDetXPerMod; 
        int nImgXY, nImgZ;  
        int nSlicePerProcess, n2Group;
        int FFTLen;

        // float param
        float pitch;
        float isoOffX, isoOffZ;
        float fov, dfov;
        float imgCentX, imgCentY, imgCentZ;
        float sdd, srad, drad;
        float dDetX, dDetZ, dDetU, dDetV, interModGapX, dDetSampleRes;

        std::vector<float> winArray;

        bool interleave;

        // enum
        bpInterpType16 iType;
    };
```

In the code that calls this dll, the vector winArrar is valued like following:

```
// caller.cpp
    static ScanParam16 param;
    param.FFTLen = 2048;
    float* wArray = new float[param.FFTLen];
    GenKernCoef(wArray, param.FFTLen, kType, ParaDataFloat, aram.dDetSampleRes);
    std::vector<float> v(wArray, wArray+param.FFTLen);
    param.winArray = v;
```

Everything looks fine now. I can see that `param.winArray` is properly set with correct values.

However, when I pass the `param` as a parameter , the `param.winArray` becomes 0 in capacity/length as I observe inside the dll.

Here is how the param gets passed:

```
//caller.cpp
    ReconAxial16 operator;
    operator.Init( param ) ;
```

Above is the point right before the parameter is passed down to the dll.

And below is the point where the parameter gets inside of the dll:

```
// dll.cpp
    void ReconAxial16::Init(const ScanParam16& param )                      
    {
        /**************************************************************/
        //                  setup geometry and detv
        /**************************************************************/
        SetupGeometry(param);   

        // Allocate buffer for reconstructed image (on cpu side)
        _img = (float *)malloc(_nImgXY * _nImgXY * sizeof(float));

        ......

    }
```

Here when I step in, I can see `param.winArray` is of length 0, but all the other parameters look fine.

I don't under stand it, and wondering how can I pass the vector properly? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you mix C-arrays with `std::vector`?

Comment: Where do you set `ScanParam16::FFTLen`? It seems like it's not being set just after you initialise `static ScanParam16 param;` so the variable `wArray` will be empty.

Comment: @Torbjörn I was trying to pass the array directly, but the array get "lost" pretty much similarly when it gets into the dll. So I tried vector to see it I can get around it.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury Right before the new operator. See update. Sorry, did not show.

Comment: Is it possible that the dll was built with different compilers or settings, or with a different version of the common header? Print `sizeof(ScanParam16)` and the offset of `winArray` from the beginning of the structure, e. g. `(int)(&((ScanParam16*)0)->winArray)`, in both  the caller and the callee, and make sure they match.

Comment: @kkm They are of different size. In the caller it is 156, in the callee(dll) it is 160. So....what happened? I use both VS2010 to build the projects.

Comment: If you can recompile both, make sure you use exactly same compiler and settings for both. If your OS is Windows, MS compilers are notoriously differ in their C++ ABI both from from version to version and between Debug and Release builds. You cannot pass C++ object from e. g. release-compiled binary to a debug-compiled DLL, or similarly mix VS2013 and VS2015 and so on. I've seen inconsistencies in g++-compiled binaries too, but they are less common.Then try to figure out what changed. My guess it's the `sizeof(std::vector<float>)` that differs between the two. dll's one is larger:a debug build?

Comment: @kkm I think built both with Debug option, and launch the Debug version because I wanted to debug.

Comment: I mean, if it is too mysterious, perhaps I should just strip the array from the  struct then pass the array independently?

Comment: I do not know, and "mysterious" is subjective. If by "array" you mean the `std::vector` embedded in the struct, and `sizeof(std::vector<float>)` is different in the two binaries, then it's not going to work anyway. You may also avoid the issue by passing a pointer to a caller-allocated memory (a C-style array), provided the callee does not need to manipulate it. You can still use a `vector` and pass a pointer to the first element in all practical cases I can think of (although this is not standardized before C++17).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually don't have an answer to this questions, but I am just presenting how I did what I wanted by getting around it.

I basically strip out the array/vector from the struct, and passed it separately as the second argument, something like this:

```
 //caller.cpp
    ReconAxial16 operator;
float* wArray = new float[param.FFTLen];
    GenKernCoef(wArray, param.FFTLen, kType, ParaDataFloat, param.dDetSampleRes);
    operator.Init( param, wArray ) ;
```

Of course in the dll project, I did something like this to make it accept an array as an additional argument:

```
// dll.h
LONG SetupGeometry( const ScanParam16 &param, float* wArray);
```

It worked. I stepped in, and saw the `wArray` get passed correctly into the dll.